# Configuración HmailServer

Tags: web

Tengo una consulta: ¿ alguien ha trabajado con  HmailServer, como se configuran los puertos? internamente funciona correctamente, pero cuando envió un correo a un servidor externo como Gmail no salen los correos.

Comment: No lo conozco pero, tienes como ver logs de Hmailserver? Es posible que esté entregando los emails pero gmail los esté viendo como spam.

Comment: No me llegan al SPAM tenemos el servicio con godaddy, tenemos los puertos smpt,pop3,imap @Alfabravo